# To give less weight-age to repetitive words in result of Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have implemented Full Text Search on one of Sql Server 2008 Table. I am using containstable query to get the result and sorting it on the basis of Rank.

Example

```
SELECT Ad_text.*, k.rank
FROM Ad_text
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Ad_text, text, 'Wanted or Engineers or bride') k
ON Ad_text.id = k.[KEY] order by rank desc
```

Now when query returns result, it  rank those rows higher which have high number of frequency of any of these words where as i want those rows to be ranked higher which has all these words.

Like  query will return result in this way

1. Wanted Wanted Wanted Groom (Rank 200)
2. Wanted Engineers For (Rank 180)
3. Wanted Bride for Engineers Rank(190)

where as i want third one to be ranked higher. Is there is any to tell containstable that not increase weight for repetitive text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround has used FreeTextSearch with its number of records feature. It solve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Most of the search engine oriended sites are use `FULL-TEXT-SEARCH`.
    It will be very faster compare to `select` and `LIKE`...
    I have added one example and some links ...
    I think it will be useful for you...
    In this full text search have some conditions also...

**STEP:1**

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    body TEXT,
    FULLTEXT (title,body)
);
```

**STEP:2**

```
INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
    ('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
    ('How To Use MySQL Well','After you went through a ...'),
    ('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
    ('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
    ('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
    ('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');
```

**STEP:3** 
*Natural Language Full-Text Searches:*

```
SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('database');
```

*Boolean Full-Text Searches*

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Go through this links
[viralpatel.net](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/full-text-search-using-mysql-full-text-search-capabilities/),[devzone.zend.com](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/),[sqlmag.com](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server-70/sample-full-text-search-engine-8967),[colorado.edu](http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/usip_exmpl_srch.html),[en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search)